# Union of the cycles in a graph

Tags: c++, graph-theory

[image: connected graph]I have set of nodes and edges and i used Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest closed cycles.My cycles are connected to each other (small black cycles in the graph). that mean, for 2 cycles, there is a common edge. Now, I want to get the Most outer cycles (red cycle in the figure), which contains all the shortest cycles. I think this is a kind of union. Not sure. is there any specific method or algorithmic method to obtain the most outer cycle from the available shortest closed cycles within the graph? How would be implement this?

Here, i tag the question under c++ also, as most programmers do know how to get the union of connected cycles and i also wish to implement this in c++. thank you in advance.

I have edited and upload a figure to my original post, as this was not clear for others.

Comment: The word "I" is capitalised in English.

Comment: What exactly is a union of cycles? Is it a set of nodes or do you need a huge cycle traversing through all of them once, or is it a huge cycle using every node several times?

Comment: At least to me it isn't clear what you mean with "union of all cycles". You might mean to find all biconnected components in an undirected graph or strongly connected components in a directed graph. There are algorithms for this and at least the latter is implemented by [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html).

Comment: @Boris Strandjev: sorry for making confuse. Yes, I have detected all the shortest closed cycles, available within a graph. All the cycles are connected to each other. that mean, there is a one common edge for 2 cycles. Now, I want to omit inside edges and need to get the outer most closed cycle. I think, this is a union of all the connected cycles. Hope, now my question is clear. thanks

Comment: @user1199463 `here is a one common edge for 2 cycles.` one common edge or node? I am asking because not every graph has such property.

Comment: @ Boris Strandjev: yes, one common edge. i was trying to upload a figure, but couldnt as i dont have much credits

Comment: Consider a tetrahedron shaped graph. What kind of answer do you expect in this case?

Comment: Still the question is not explicit enough: Are the nodes positioned somehow in the space? If not why did you chose exactly this to be the red nodes, and how do you define outer?

Comment: This is not a tetrahedron. Please answer the question about a tetrahedron shaped graph.

Comment: @Boris Strandjev: me, i am poor in graph theory and cant give you a exact answere. all my nodes are in one plane. Dijkstra's algorithm gave me the all the shortest cycles. now i want to most outer cycle. i am also looking for a way to get this.

Comment: @n.m.: i donot have any idea about that graph. all my nodes and edges lie on a plane.

Comment: Sorry @user1199463, tell us the exact problem you are trying to solve: how do you determine the edges that exist, it might be that the shortest cycles as you call them is not the way to go at all. Currently for me this question seems like convex cover of set of points.

Comment: Do you have coordinates of each vertex? Can you guarantee your edges are non-intersecting straight line segments? You should perhaps update your question, because this is a totally different problem.

Comment: i dont have coordinates and considered length of each edge is equal to 1. i think, i have to remove the common edges between connected loops and work with the other edges and should find the connectivity of the remaining edge's nodes. but, this is a long way and do not have any theory. any help please. –

Comment: Look @user1199463, you might not be an expert of Graph theory. this is fine. Still some people might be able to find you. I believe I might be such person. However, I can not help you if you are not explicit enough of the input and the expected output of your problem. If you don't have any coordinates why have you drown the graph just like that, not any other way (which btw will influence your red line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, you're trying to find an edge-maximal face of a connected [planar graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph). There's an algorithm for enumerating faces of a planar graph in the Boost library: [Planar Face Traversal](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0_beta1/libs/graph/doc/planar_face_traversal.html). You may use it to iterate over graph's faces and find the one with most edges involved.

Notes:

- This will really only work for **planar graphs**
- For many graphs, the solution is **not unique**, consider graph of a regular polyhedron - here, all faces have the same degree, so it's not well defined which one of them is the 'outer cycle' you're looking for

[image: regular polyhedron graph example (Attribution: Tomruen at en.wikipedia)]

- What 'face with most edges involved' means is different for graphs which are **2-connected** and which are not. If it is not 2-connected, there will be "branches" reaching into some of the faces, and by definition, the same face lies on both sides of such a branch. Depending on your liking/needs you may either count such edges into the length of the face or omit them, getting different results.

Answer (score 1):

Boost [geometry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html) seems contains [what](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models/model_polygon.html) you need, but it's rather abstract, and I need some time to relate to your question. Apparently, [within](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/within/within_2.html) could be applied to each pair of rings, to determine the perimeter.
Or better, find the ring with maximum area.